# Why did Shazam! take place in a real city?

Tags: dc-extended-universe, comic-adaptation, shazam

The movie [Shazam](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0448115/) takes place in Philadelphia, Pennsylvania. This is different than most DC movies and shows in which they all take place in fictional cities.  Superman is in Metropolis. Batman is in Gotham. Flash is in Central City. The Green Arrow is in Star City. In the comics, Shazam (Captain Marvel) lives in [Fawcett City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fawcett_City).

Was there any official word from the writers or producers as to why they chose to use a real city over a fictional one?

Comment: Because they got sick of answering "so where's that place located exactly" questions? :P

Comment: @Jenayah valid point :D

Comment: For what it's worth, Wonder Woman used several real-world cities.  Paris and London for sure, and I forget where they were in Belgium.  Even the original Christopher Reeves Superman movies had some real cities - Pisa, Italy comes to mind, and they visited the President in one of them, who would presumably be in D.C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Andrew Dyce's January 2019 [interview](https://screenrant.com/shazam-movie-interview-director/) with director David F. Sandberg in screenrant:

> **Q:** Was there a reason that you chose Philadelphia?
>
> **Sandberg:** Well, we went with Geoff Johns' idea. I think he picked Philly because of Benjamin Franklin and all of that stuff. And the thing about Shazam, or Captain Marvel, is it's been different. It was Fawcett City at some point, but I think originally, it was New York. So it's not like, "Oh, it has to be Metropolis or something." It can be anything really.

[Geoff Johns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoff_Johns) writes the *Shazam!* comic books ("vol. 3 #1-ongoing"), see also [The New 52 relaunch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_(DC_Comics)#The_New_52_relaunch) and [DC Rebirth and beyond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_(DC_Comics)#DC_Rebirth_and_beyond).

Comment: Oh! I wasn't aware it was moved to Philadelphia in the relaunch.